# Passing new struct as parameter

Tags: objective-c

I have a function like so:

```
- (void)addBalloon:(COLOR)color:(VELOCITY)velocity:(LOCATION)location
```

Where COLOR is an enum, and VELOCITY and LOCATION are structs defined in a constants header file..

VELOCITY and LOCATION both store two ints, x and y.

When calling this method, I would call it like so:

```
VELOCITY vel;
LOCATION loc;

vel.x = 100.0;
vel.y = 0.0;

loc.x = 10.0;
loc.y = 10.0;

[self addBalloon:Red:vel:loc];
```

But to me, this seems disorganized. I would like to call the function directly in one line while creating the struct on the line..

Here is my question: I'm not sure if this can be done using #define.. but if it can't.. is the only other viable option creating a function that returns VELOCITY or LOCATION and takes inputs x, and y?

I would like to do something like the following:

```
[self addBalloon:Red:VELOCITY(100.0, 0.0):LOCATION(10.0, 10.0)];
```

Comment: Please have text between the colons. See how you have no part of the method name before each colon? No where in the SDK does this happen so you shouldn't do it yourself. (http://i.stack.imgur.com/DCu5T.png)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the C99 syntax for designated initialisers:

```
[self addBalloon:Red:(VELOCITY){100.0, 0.0}:(LOCATION){10.0, 10.0}];
```

or

```
[self addBalloon:Red:(VELOCITY){.x=100.0, .y=0.0}:(LOCATION){.x=10.0, .y=10.0}];
```